# xsl to reset a existing line level element value using a header level element in an XML

Tags: xslt

Happy new year all,

I have a requirement to reset a line level element value with the header level element value. Below is the input XML and expected output XML, any guidance is appreciated. I tried few ways to template match but I am unable to produce the expected result.

Input:

```
<Products>
   <Company>ABC</Company>
   <City>Pandora</City>
   <Product>
      <Name>Avatar</Name>
      <MadeInCity>New York</MadeInCity>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      <Name>Titanic</Name>
      <MadeInCity>San Francisco</MadeInCity>
   </Product>
   ....
</Products>
```

Output:

```
<Products>
   <Company>ABC</Company>
   <Product>
      <Name>Avatar</Name>
      <MadeInCity>Pandora</MadeInCity>
   </Product>
   <Product>
      <Name>Titanic</Name>
      <MadeInCity>Pandora</MadeInCity>
   </Product>
   ....
</Products>
```

As shown above, I want to do below things using XSL

1. Replace the values of *Products/Product/MadeInCity* element value with *Products/City* element value
2. Remove the element *Products/City*

Below is what I have attempted

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Products/Product/MadeInCity">
        <value>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Products/City">
                    <xsl:value-of select="Products/City"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </value>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-Thank you

Comment: Post your attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Updated the XSL I have tried

Comment: Is there a real possibility of the `/Products/City` element not existing?

Comment: yeah, it is possible because of an upstream system instability. If /Products/City element is missing no transformation is needed then input and output are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- if City exists, replace the value of MadeInCity  -->
<xsl:template match="/Products[City]/Product/MadeInCity">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="/Products/City"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove City -->
<xsl:template match="City"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you for the response and solving it. /Products[City]/Product/MadeInCity is this match expression doing two matches like /Products/City exists and /Products/Product/MadeInCity exists?

Comment: It's a conditional match: it matches `MadeInCity` only if its `Product` grandparent has a `City` child (lookup *predicate*). Otherwise the *identity transform* template kicks in.